# Begin each line with a star?

Tags: emacs, doxygen

When editing a `.dox` file, each line after the first one needs to begin with a space and a star. Is there a way to automate that with `emacs`?

Here is an example:

```
/*! \mainpage Introduction to the Framework
 *
 * \section toc On this page:
 * 1. \ref s_mot <br>
 * 2. \ref s_features <br>
 *
 * \section s_mot Motivation
 * This is the introduction.
 *
 * \section s_features Features
 * 
 *
 * \copyright MIT License
 * \warning Boost and Cairo come with their respective licences
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the buffer in `c-mode` (`M-x c-mode`), and use `c-indent-new-comment-line` (bound to `C-M-j` and `M-j`).

Comment: This puts only the space. I need `" * "`. Also, it highlights the whole file as `C` comments, which is tiresome when one needs to work on this text for a prolonged amount of time.

Comment: It makes the next line look like the previous line.  If you add the ` * ` in the line after `/*!`, it will do the right thing from then on.  You could also turn off the syntax highlighting with `M-x font-lock-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an optimal solution, perhaps, but if you can get away with adding the asterisks afterwards, you can select the first two columns of the whole region where you want to add asterisks and use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>  <kbd>SPACE *</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>. This will do `string-rectangle`, filling the region with `" *"`.

This is probably fine for the first time you write the file, but if you need to add additional, non-consecutive, lines afterwards, it might be a bit of a pain.

---

Here's a better way:

```
(defun newline-with-asterisk ()
  "Newline and asterisk"
  (interactive "*")
  (insert "
 * "))

(add-hook 'doxygen-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-with-asterisk)))
```

This binds <kbd>RET</kbd> to do what you want, assuming your `.dox` files use `doxygen-mode`. If they use a different major mode, just change `doxygen-mode-hook` to the appropriate varaible.

Comment: I actually use doxymacs: http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/ It's not been updated in a while, though.

Comment: How does `doxymacs` help with this? I didn't notice anything in it related to the question...

Comment: Nothing specifically, aside from it gives you a doxygen-related mode to add  the hook to. It can insert skeleton doxygen comments though, with the basic layout. It just doesn't seem to have something for adding asterisks on newlines.